# Using ASP.Net MVC UI Helpers in a classic ASP.Net project

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, ui-helper

Just wondering if anyone know if in general you can use the MVC UI helpers in a classic ASP.Net project. Obviously you would have to be mindful not to you the form helper, etc. But I have some helpers that I have built for MVC and wondering if there is anyway I can use them as is in my older project.

I know I would need to reference the MVC dll's etc, but I'm trying to think is there any traps with doing this (i.e. the page life-cycle screwing things up) or any major reasons why you shouldn't do this... My thinking is that asp.net controls work in asp.net (with some restrictions), so does it work the other way round.

Cheers 
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman's [Plug-in Hybrids article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) provides a pretty good treatment of the process of integrating ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC pages side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

The last chapter of [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079) details using MVC and WebForms side by side.

Off the top of my head, I can tell you that you must be using the Web Application project type, not Web Site.